# How to export a cell array into Excel with Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab

i got a cell array looks like this

```
'NIPPON TELEGRAPH & TELPHONE COR'
'IMMERSION CORP'
[]
'NISSAN MOTOR CO LTD'
[]
[]
[]
[]
<1x5 cell>
'STERIS CORP'
<1x134 cell>
[]
<1x4 cell>
[]
<1x2 cell>
```

This is a list of companies' name, the empty brackets means the name not available, <1x4 cell> means in that cell there are four companies' name. Now I want to export this array in to Excel, especially i want to put those  <1x4 cell> alike cells in to four seperate cells in the same row in Excel. How can I do that?

Comment: Check out `xlswrite`, give it a shot and post your attempt

Comment: I tried in different ways of xlswrite, it doesnt work..

Comment: Post your best try. Also it would help if you made your example a cell matrix that we could just copy and paste to use as example data.

Answer (score 0):

`xlswrite` will not automatically handle the combination of char arrays, cells and empty matrices very well. You could do a loop where you write to the file for each case where the cell array is not empty.  However, if you have data like the above where C{1} is a char array and C{some n} = a cell array of names, it becomes somewhat inelegant:

```
for n = 1:length(C)
    if ischar(C{n})
      xlswrite('testfile.xls',C(n),1, sprintf('A%d',n));
    elseif iscell(C{n})
      xlswrite('testfile.xls',C{n},1, sprintf('A%d',n));
    end
end
```

In the case where every C{n} is a cell array (the first being a <1x1 cell>) it could become:

```
for n = 1:length(C)
    if ~isempty(C{n})
      xlswrite('testfile.xls',C{n},1, sprintf('A%d',n));
    end
end
```

---

My test data:

```
C{1} = 'TEST NAME';
C{4} = {'TEST','TEST2'};
```